# OpenGL texture not rendered properly on model

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, rendering, assimp

In my opengl application, texture is not rendered correctly on the model.

Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Here is what the bunny should look like:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTZaG.jpg)

Here is the code to load the texture.

```
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1); 
m_LocalBuffer = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &m_Width, &m_Height, &m_BPP, 0); 

GLCall(glGenTextures(1, &m_RendererID));
GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID));
GLCall(glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D));
GLenum format = GL_RGBA;

//..switching on m_BPP to set format, omitted here

GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
GLCall(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));

GLCall(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, m_Width, m_Height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_LocalBuffer));

GLCall(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));

if (m_LocalBuffer) {
    stbi_image_free(m_LocalBuffer);
}
```

Here is the texture file I'm using
[Texture File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEgDJ.jpg)

I downloaded the asset from https://blenderartists.org/t/uv-unwrapped-stanford-bunny-happy-spring-equinox/1101297 (the 3.3Mb link)

Here is the code where I read in the texCoords

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++) {
    //..read in positions and normals

    if (mesh->mTextureCoords[0]) {
        vertex.TexCoords.x = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x;
        vertex.TexCoords.y = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y;
    }        
}
```

I'm loading the model as an obj file using assimp. I just read the texture coord from the result and pass it to the shader. (GLCall is just a debug macro I have in the renderer)

What could potentially be the cause for this? Let me know if more info is needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide the texture file? How is the rabbit supposed to look like? Is the uv checker another texture?

Comment: @AdrienGivry Thanks for your reply! I've updated the question. And I believe the provided texture is the texture for the whole thing. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @JoyceChen Is the texture flipped along the y-axis (v)?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you! yes it turns out I shouldn't flip it vertically when I load the image (needed before when using png files). Works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image seems to be flipped vertically (around the x-axis). To compensated that, you've to flip the image manually, after loading it. Or if you've flipped the image then you've to omit that. Whether the image has to be flipped or not, depends on the image format.